# Is there a standard notation for a 'switch' type BPM node?

Tags: business-process-management, bpmn

Did not find a more suitable SE site, so asking this here.

In BPM, there are more-or-less standard ways of marking activities - like Start (green circle), Stop (red circle), Conditional (yellow diamond). An example I found is [here](http://help.bizagi.com/bpmsuite/en/performactivity_01vacationrequestprocess_zoom91.png).

Conditional is basically an 'if' in any programming language.

What I could not find any example of is a 'switch'.

I know that one could use multiple Conditionals, but I have to implement a user friendly way, so I'd like to know if there is any standard way of representing such a thing in BPM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "switch". If you want to switch process flow in one or another way you can use **Complex Gateway**. A Complex Gateway allows the modeler to specify any arbitrary rules needed to determine how to emit tokens or process arriving tokens.

[image]

BPMN Complex Gateways can be used for splitting or merging a complicated process flow scenario. However, it is **not recommended** practice as there are simpler and more practical inclusive and exclusive gateways. There is always better to use their combination. You can learn more about complex gateways [here](https://developer.appway.com/screen/ShowSingleRecipe/selectedRecipeId/1483526230486).

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that these were called gateways.

Comment: In my opinion a "switch" with "break" instruction for each "case" is exactly an exclusive gateway: only one outgoing transition will be taken. If several "case" lead to the same code execution it would be closer to an inclusive gateway.